# DotNetOpenId "Login failed". The characters in login

Tags: dotnetopenauth

In my project I use OpenIdProviderWebForms and OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms from the library [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/).

Validation is done by user request to a domain server.

Login my users are in the format **test_dm\username** and **username@test.dm.ru**

Authorization for the provider is successful, but when the openid.GetResponse (); I get the error "Login failed (Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.)".

As I found out, problems arise because of the characters `.` and `/!` (I replace \ with /!) in the username.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID never transmits usernames between the two web sites.  What code (in your web app presumably) is responsible for putting the username in the URL?  I suggest you use `Uri.EscapeDataString` to escape the username before you put it in your URL.

Comment: Using `Uri.EscapeDataString` in this case does not lead to problems with the point (as it does not replace it). 

With the backslash different situation - it is replaced, but when you create a Uri escape-sequence is replaced by a slash, and I have LocalIdentifier cover those data as before.

`public static Identifier BuildIdentityUrl(string username) {
 return new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, HttpContext.Current.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/user.aspx/" + Uri.EscapeDataString(username)));
}`